# Docker on Linux: All actions (hello-world, pull image, etc) yield timeouts

Tags: linux, docker, nameservers

I know this is a common question, but I've spent two hours trying to get past `docker run hello-world` and am totally stumped.

Everything I try yields a net/http waiting for connection timeout.

**Running** `docker login`:

```
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: ******
Password: 
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

**Running hello-world**:

```
mike@tictac:~$ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'docker run --help'.
```

My docker version is a clean install AFAIK:

```
mike@tictac:~$ docker --version
Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
```

I've tried adding 8.8.8.8 to my /etc/resolv.conf to no avail:

```
mike@tictac:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
search home
nameserver 127.0.0.53
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

I think my /etc/hosts file is also fine:

```
mike@tictac:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   tictac
8.8.8.8     tictac

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Here's my docker info:

```
mike@tictac:~$ docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 18.09.0
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: c4446665cb9c30056f4998ed953e6d4ff22c7c39
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.15.0-33-generic
Operating System: Linux Mint 19
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 12
Total Memory: 15.37GiB
Name: tictac
ID: J54P:ILHO:J76M:AF27:MDKJ:BIDS:WODK:MA6N:IICP:TIMJ:BIUN:H56O
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
HTTP Proxy: http://proxy.example.com:80/
HTTPS Proxy: http://1.1.1.1:111
No Proxy: localhost,127.0.0.1,docker-registry.somecorporation.com
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

And I've confirmed that docker is indeed running:

```
mike@tictac:~$ sudo service docker status

    ● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
      Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
               └─10_docker_proxy.conf, http-proxy.conf
       Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-11-16 11:06:36 EST; 6min ago
         Docs: https://docs.docker.com
     Main PID: 6190 (dockerd)
        Tasks: 22
       CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
               └─6190 /usr/bin/dockerd -H unix://
```

If I could just get through hello-world, I would be so happy.

EDIT: Also relevant, I can curl URL directly just fine:

```
mike@tictac:~/Projects/conserve-with-us/conserve-with-us-api$ curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases like this I usually suspect proxy configurations and your `docker info` also shows some inconsistent HTTP/HTTPS and bypass configurations.

```
HTTP Proxy: http://proxy.example.com:80/
HTTPS Proxy: http://1.1.1.1:111
No Proxy: localhost,127.0.0.1,docker-registry.somecorporation.com
```

Usually most people doesn't need to set these at all, but some companies enforce non-transparent proxy settings, but in these cases the first 2 usually the same and for bypass config it may include the `/var/run/docker.sock` as well.

I would remove or reset all your proxy configuration both for the docker deamon and client to make sure they all match-up:

- `dockerd proxy` proxy config: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/
- `docker client` proxy config: https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/

So if you need to setup a non-transparent proxy, I would also make sure that your `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` and `proxy_bypass` environment variables are also matching your expected proxy config:

```
env | grep proxy
```

So you would see the same results with curl or other linux apps which supports these.

Comment: Thanks so much!  It ended up being my proxy configs (I had installed a few things in the instructions which, not only did I not need, but actually made my install not work).  `sudo rm -rf /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux mint simply go to network in systems-settings, there in the settings button of you connected network you will find DNS field in ipv4/ipv6 section.